# XML Nodes Count is zero

Tags: c#, xml

I have C# project in .Net 2.0.  I am trying to read all Event nodes and stores its TextData  property in a list of string. But following SelectNodes has zero count.

What is the best way to store all TextData values from all Event nodes, in a List of strings?

Note: Some event nodes will not have TextData.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"D:\\Lijo\1.xml");

XmlNodeList xnList = doc.SelectNodes("/Events/Event");
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<TraceData xmlns="http://tempuri.org/TracePersistence.xsd">
  <Header>
    <TraceProvider name="Microsoft SQL Server" MajorVersion="9" MinorVersion="0" BuildNumber="3282" />
  </Header>
  <Events>
    <Event id="15" name="Audit Logout">
      <Column id="12" name="SPID">57</Column>
      <Column id="14" name="StartTime">2014-04-20T18:00:30.573-04:00</Column>
      <Column id="16" name="Reads">6512</Column>
      <Column id="18" name="CPU">0</Column>
      <Column id="9" name="ClientProcessID">3884</Column>
      <Column id="13" name="Duration">70046000</Column>
      <Column id="17" name="Writes">0</Column>
    </Event>


    <Event id="10" name="RPC:Completed">
      <Column id="12" name="SPID">57</Column>
      <Column id="14" name="StartTime">2014-04-20T18:01:40.637-04:00</Column>
      <Column id="16" name="Reads">76</Column>
      <Column id="18" name="CPU">0</Column>
      <Column id="1" name="TextData">exec uspTranslationsGetTranslationByPageName @PageName='invWLUnSuspendReasonCode.aspx',@LanguageID=1</Column>
      <Column id="9" name="ClientProcessID">3884</Column>
      <Column id="13" name="Duration">226</Column>
      <Column id="17" name="Writes">0</Column>
    </Event>

  </Events>
</TraceData>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `XmlNamespaceManager` to add prefix to namespace URI mapping. Then use the prefix in the XPath to access elments in corresponding namespace.

```
var nsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsManager.AddNamespace("d", "http://tempuri.org/TracePersistence.xsd");

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"D:\\Lijo\1.xml");

XmlNodeList xnList = doc.SelectNodes("//d:Events/d:Event", nsManager);
```

**UPDATE :**

To get all `TextData` in a list of string, you can try this way :

```
XmlNodeList xnList = doc.SelectNodes("d:TraceData/d:Events/d:Event/d:Column[@name='TextData']", nsManager);
var result = new List<string>();
foreach (XmlNode node in xnList)
{
    result.Add(node.InnerText);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read `XML` for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Home>
  <TextEntries>
  <follow>
      <item visible="true" navid="fb" url="https://www.facebook.com/" type="text" hideineditor="false" esbname="facebook  Follow Link" linktype="new" id="200038"><![CDATA[facebook]]></item>
      <item visible="true" navid="twitter" url="https://twitter.com/" type="text" hideineditor="false" esbname="twitter  Follow Link" linktype="new" id="200039"><![CDATA[twitter]]></item>
   </follow>
 </TextEntries>
</Home>
```

**Reading Nodes:**

```
  XmlElement root = null;
  XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
  doc.Load(sourceXmlFilePath);
  root = doc.DocumentElement;
  XmlNode rootnode = root.SelectSingleNode("//Home//TextEntries");
  XmlNode followNode = root.SelectSingleNode("//Home//TextEntries//follow");
  string myAttribute=followNode.ChildNodes[0].Attributes["id"].Value;//this will read the attribute ID of first inner element
 string myFirstInnerNodeValue=followNode.ChildNodes[0].InnerText;//this will read the data of first inner node i.e facebook
```

Hope this helps you!